# A simple use of nuxtJS with Axios and VueX

Tags: vue.js, axios, vuex, nuxt.js

I'm discovering VueJS and I have troubles querying an API.
There are (too) many resources, and it looks like there is a different approach for each tutorial I meet. Now I'm getting lost...

The project is a little 3 pages showcase. Content is provided by an API, one endpoint for each language. I would like to use VueX to store the data, and to update it according to a language switch interaction.

Following the documentation, the "classical" approach is deprecated, and I use the "modules" approach. Still, I suppose that it's ok to centralize data at the store root as only one API call is required:

`/store/index.js`

```js
import axios from "axios";

// STATE - Initial values
export const state = () => ({
  content: {}
});

// ACTIONS - Asynchronous operations
export const actions = () => ({
    async nuxtServerInit({ commit }) {
    // I will introduce the language variable later here
    const response = await this.$axios.$get('https://APIURL.com/fr');
    const content = response.data;
    commit("setContent", content);
  }
});

// MUTATIONS - Updates the state
export const mutations = {
  setContent(state, content) {
    state.content = content;
  }
};
```

At this point, I expect the content to be made available to the different pages or components.

`/components/A_component.vue` and/or `/pages/index.vue`

```js
...
  {{ content }}
...

// LOADS the store
import { mapState } from "vuex";

// COMPUTES the values retrieval
export default {
  computed: mapState(["content"])
};
```

However, nothing is displayed. Indeed, the `content` object is not updated and remains empty.

Comment: An action needs to be triggered by a call to [dispatch](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/actions.html#dispatching-actions). Are you calling that anywhere? Also does the content need to be stored in Vuex (I.e. could it just be fetched on each page)?

Comment: Yes, that must be a problem. I don't have any dispatch yet.  
But I didn't really understand how to us it. With nuxt, the syntax is different, and I don't have any `store` object, as in the VueX documentation. Indeed, [documentation of NuxtJS](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/vuex-store#the-nuxtserverinit-action) refers to `dispatch` within `nuxtServerInit`...  
Also, about fetching, I guess it would be more efficient to perform only one API call instead of one per page. Does fetching imply several calls?

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I finally found where the bug was coming from.

`actions` should be exported as an object, not a function:

```js
export const actions = {
    async nuxtServerInit({ commit }) {
    // I will introduce the language variable later here
    const response = await this.$axios.$get('https://APIURL.com/fr');
    const content = response.data;
    commit("setContent", content);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Example for nuxtServerInit

```js
// store/settings.js
export const mutations = {
  GET_PRICE_VIEW_FROM_SERVER(ctx, payload) {
    ctx.priceView = payload;
  }
}
```

```js
// store/index.js
import { getPriceView } from "../utils/getSettings";

export const actions = {
  nuxtServerInit({ commit }, { req }) {
    commit("setting/GET_PRICE_VIEW_FROM_SERVER", getPriceView(req));
  }
};
```

Using `nuxtServerInit` usually only for https://nuxtjs.org/api/context#the-context
I assume your `params.lng` should become from the context